# Error when adding Headless-ui in a Deno+Fresh Project

Tags: deno, preact, headless-ui

I have a `Deno+Fresh` project and when adding `headlessui` to my Fresh projec I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')`

I read the following discussion that apparently addresses my issue... https://github.com/denoland/fresh/discussions/606

But I can not make it work.

To debug the issue I created a demo project (https://github.com/datracka/test-headlessui2)

It is just a new fresh project created with `deno run -A -r https://fresh.deno.dev my-project` where I just added a new island `MySwitch`, importing directly the `headlessui` module as described in the github discussion thread.

```js
import { Switch } from "https://esm.sh/@headlessui/react@1.6.6?alias=react:preact/compat,react-dom:preact/compat,@types/react:preact/compat&deps=preact@10.10.0";
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";
import { tw } from "twind";

export default function () {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const toggleChecked = () => setChecked(!checked);

  return (
    <Switch
      checked={checked}
      onChange={toggleChecked}
      class={tw`${
        checked ? "bg-blue-600" : "bg-gray-200"
      } relative inline-flex h-6 w-11 items-center rounded-full`}
    >
      <span class={tw`sr-only`}>Enable notifications</span>
      <span
        class={tw`${
          checked ? "translate-x-6" : "translate-x-1"
        } inline-block h-4 w-4 transform rounded-full bg-white`}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

It fires the error above when running the project with `deno task start`.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue

The import was fine:

```js
import { Switch } from "https://esm.sh/@headlessui/react@1.6.6?alias=react:preact/compat,react-dom:preact/compat,@types/react:preact/compat&deps=preact@10.10.0";
```

Only you have to have in consideration the current version of `preact` in your `Fresh` project. Otherwise they collide and therefore raise the error above.

In my case the current version was `10.11.0` and not `10.10.0`

I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Thanks for this - I was able to get Radix working in a Fresh project in this way.